# Scraping with Beautifulsoup: Not all class values returned

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a few values for a website with Beautifulsoup. I am able to identify the class and export those. Unfortunately, the crucial values are missing. Would anyone here be able to help to help understand how I could retrieve all values from this class?

This is the website: https://www.hvz.baden-wuerttemberg.de/pegel.html?id=00007
This is the class: "da-spc da-tmv"

My current code looks as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# The URL of the website you want to scrape
url = "https://www.hvz.baden-wuerttemberg.de/pegel.html?id=00007"

# Send an HTTP GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    
    # Find the element with class "da-spc da-tmv"
    element = soup.find(class_="da-spc da-tmv")
    
    # Extract the value from the element (assuming it's text within the element)
    if element:
        value = element.get_text()
        print("Scraped Value:", value)
    else:
        print("Element not found.")
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the web page. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

It returns the following information:
`Scraped Value: Tagesmittel am Vortag:  W -- --     Q -- --`

But the values I am really interested in are the one which are currently replaced with "--" "--". These values will change every day.
Today, while I am writing this text here, the values are:
`Tagesmittel am Vortag:  W 372 cm 24.09.2023     Q -- --`

I would just need the `372` and ideally also the `24.09.2023`.

I would expect the whole class to get exported.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the page you mentioned, I noticed that the data you are looking for is loaded dynamically. This means that requests are made to a backend service or an API to retrieve them. Unfortunately, BeautifulSoup is not the appropriate tool for this type of task.

If you prefer to keep it simple, you can use the Python requests library to make calls to the backend and retrieve the data you need. Based on what I observed on the page, there are two main requests:

A request to load all the cities and rivers along with their IDs.
Once you have those IDs, a second request is made to retrieve the specific data you are looking for.
You can see these requests in the 'Network' section of Google Chrome's developer tools.

Below is some basic code I've prepared for you. You only need to specify the city and river from which you want to retrieve data. If in the future you need to get data from all cities, this code is easily adaptable:

```
import requests
import re
import ast


city = 'Epplings'
river = 'Obere Argen'

# first request - to get city ids
url = "https://www.hvz.baden-wuerttemberg.de/js/hvz_peg_stmn.js"
response = requests.get(url)
match = re.search(r'HVZ_Site\.PEG_DB\s*=\s*(.*?);', response.text, re.DOTALL)
if not match:
    print("error en request")
all_city_data = match.group(1).strip()

# second request - to get the desired data
url = "https://www.hvz.baden-wuerttemberg.de/js/dat-peg-tmv.js"
response = requests.get(url)
match = re.search(r'\{([^}]+)\}', response.text, re.DOTALL)
if not match:
    print("error en request")
extracted_content = "{" + match.group(1).strip() + "}"
Tagesmittels = ast.literal_eval(extracted_content)


for city_data in ast.literal_eval(all_city_data):
    try:
        if city_data[1] == city and city_data[2] == river:
            city_id = int(city_data[0])
            print(f"{Tagesmittels[city_id][1]} {Tagesmittels[city_id][2]} | {Tagesmittels[city_id][3]}")
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
37 cm | 24.09.2023
```

Comment: `+1` for staying with `requests` and use of th API that enables to get all information with just two requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling JavaScript in your browser and look at the web page then. You'll see that the values you want are not rendered. This is because requests does not support Javascript—it works with HTTP requests only.

To get the data you want, you'll have to use a web driver like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html). This loads the page in a browser and will render the same as you'd see browsing normally. If you're familiar with requests/BeautifulSoup, it's not difficult to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) is an option :

```
#pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.hvz.baden-wuerttemberg.de/pegel.html?id=00007"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    
    we = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ID_INFO_W, #ID_INFO_WTZ')
    d = {element.get_attribute("id"): element.text for element in we}
```

Output :

```
>>> print(d) # {'ID_INFO_W': '372', 'ID_INFO_WTZ': '24.09.2023'}
```